# code doesn't wait for the response before continuing in async await function

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have this code in one file:

```
...
const SMSSent = await sendSMS(phoneToSendSMS, bodyToSend)
    
        console.log('res from sendSMS', SMSSent);
    if (SMSSent?.error) {
                await prisma.token.delete({
                    where: {
                        id: res.tokenId,
                    },
                });
        console.log('-------------error sending SMS Token deleted---------------------');
        return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: "Une erreur s'est produite" }), { status: 422 });
}
    //finally return a response 200
    else return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ message: "Un SMS a été envoyé sur votre téléphone" }), { status: 200 });
}
```

And it call the sendSMS

```
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { accept: "application/json", "content-type": "application/json", "api-key": process.env.BREVO_API_KEY },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            sender: "maillart",
            recipient: phoneNumber,
            content: body,
            type: "transactional",
            unicodeEnabled: false,
            tag: "accountValidation",
        }),
    };
    fetch("https://api.brevo.com/v3/transactionalSMS/sms", options)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log("-------res is comming--------", data);
                if (data.message) {
                    console.log("-------------------------SMS not sent1-------------------------------", data.message);
                    return data.message;
                }
                console.log("-------------------------SMS sent-------------------------------");
                return { error: "Une erreur s'est produite" }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("-------------------------SMS not sent2-------------------------------");
                console.log("erreur ::", err);
                return { error: "Une erreur s'est produite" };
            });
}
```

but this is not working as expected because I always receive

```
res from sendSMS undefined
```

before any other logs and response
ex:

```
res from sendSMS undefined
-------res is comming-------- { code: 'invalid_parameter', message: 'Invalid telephone number' }
-------------------------SMS not sent1------------------------------- Invalid telephone number
```

I tried many different way to write this code and debug this but I didn't succeed.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you probably need to return the `fetch` promise from `sendSMS` if you want to `await` it - note: by "probably" I actually mean "definitely"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting something in an async function and awaiting on that function does not automatically make them synchronous.

To fix this, you need to also put await on the fetch call:

```
const sendSMS = async () => {
  const res = await fetch();
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
};

const data = await sendSMS();
```

Or just return the promise from fetch (note `sendSMS` does not have to be an async funtion in this case):

```
const sendSMS = () => {
  
  return fetch("https://api.brevo.com/v3/transactionalSMS/sms", options)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((err) => {});
};

const data = await sendSMS();
```

Comment: Thank you, Return the fetch promise was obviously the solution !